# Using an alias defined in `FROM` part, instead of a column result sub‑query: is it possible?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

### Question

For readability mainly, while I know I could achieve the same with a `TEMPORARY TABLE`, I would like to avoid the latter (personal preference to have the whole in a single query).

The question is asked in the context of standard SQL.

### Abstract case

Say I have something about like this:

```
SELECT a, (a IN (SELECT … )) as b,
FROM t
```

Is there any way to have something like this instead:

```
SELECT a, (a IN u) as b,
FROM t, (SELECT … ) as u
```

If I do this, the database engine (which is actually SQLite, for the anecdote), complains the table `u` is unknown. I though is would be visible, as it would be possible to use `u` as a column prefix.

I know I can do this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS u AS SELECT … ;
SELECT a, (a IN u) as b,
FROM t
```

However, as I said above, I would like to avoid it, as I want a monolithic query (due to personal preferences).

That's mainly for readability when the sub‑query is a bit large, and it does not need to be a lot large, to prevent good readability.

Comment: Your suggested syntax is not valid in any other database.

Comment: In which snippet? I know the second snippet is invalid, as this is the one which led me to the question.

Comment: . . The `(a in u)` part.  You should write:  `a in (select ? from u)`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That was precisely why the question existed. I was asking for an alternative to this impossible construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the database engine (which is actually SQLite, for the anecdote)

In SQLite you could use [`Common Table Expressions`](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH u(col) AS
(
  SELECT col FROM b
)
SELECT a, (a IN u) AS b
FROM t;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2997f/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦═══╗
║ a  ║ b ║
╠════╬═══╣
║ 1  ║ 0 ║
║ 2  ║ 1 ║
║ 3  ║ 1 ║
║ 4  ║ 0 ║
╚════╩═══╝
```

Comment: Ah, OK. I never used `WITH` so far. Will look at it in the doc, see if it's standard SQL, and may select your answer. Just the time for me to check … Already thanks to have mentioned `WITH`

Comment: @Hibou57 `WITH` is supported by `Oracle/Postgresql/SQLite/SQL Server`. Please note that `(a IN u)` will not work in SQL Server and PostgreSQL

Comment: Just checked: after [SQL Reserved Words Overview (developer.mimer.se)](http://developer.mimer.se/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml),`WITH` seems to exists since SQL92.

Comment: @Hibou57 Yes, but remember that it is recommendation, not every vendor implements it. For example MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, SQLite only.

Comment: For an anecdote, `WITH` is available since SQLite 3.8.3, and Ubuntu Trusty is unfortunately stuck with 3.8.2. Needs a whole system upgrade to upgrade SQLite :-/